# Missing artifact com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-cucumber5:pom:0.0.1

Tags: reportportal

I am getting missing artifact while trying to build the project, please suggest a solution

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>agent-java-cucumber5</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Repository used:
<repositories>
  <repository>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   <id>bintray-epam-reportportal</id>
   <name>bintray</name>
   <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

Comment: is so wide question would you mind to share version of jdk and logs

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, because it is here, you can download it by a direct link:
http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal/com/epam/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber5/0.0.1/

Anyway I'm going to delete it in a few days. Version `0.0.1` does not work due to a bug, please use the latest one:
https://bintray.com/epam/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber5/5.0.0-RC-1